# HtmlDecode inside a C# library

Tags: c#

I have a C# library that does a web request towards an api.

I receive this string:

```
Appartement de 42m&#178; en vente &#224; 225 000&#8364;, Bagnolet
```

I would like to decode the &#... characters with `WebUtility.HtmlDecode`

However, in the reference wizard, I can't find system.net.webutility.
Do you know how can I reference the assembly please ?

Thank you !

Ps: I use C# 4.6
[image]

Comment: Add `System.Net` & the corresponding `using` and your good to go (Thats where `WebUtility` lives)

Comment: @AlexK. Yes, do you know what using should I add ?

Comment: `using System.Net;`

Comment: Mmmmmh I feel so foolish right now ... Thank you dude !

Comment: @AlexK. - [`WebUtility`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility(v=vs.110).aspx) is in the `System` assembly, not `System.Net` - @Vivien - always check the documentation for a class to discover its assembly (the reference you need) and namespace (for the `using` directive or to fully name the type)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I just checked again in my solution: WebUtility is part of namespace System.Net

Comment: @VivienAdnot - **namespace** `System.Net`. **assembly** `System`. It's important to realise that they're separate things. That's why you don't need a *reference* to `System.Net`, since references are an *assembly* concept, but you do need a `using` directive since that's a *namespace* concept. And why Alex K was somewhat incorrect in stating that you needed to "Add `System.Net` *and* add a `using`" since that implied that the first action was to add a reference.

Answer (score 0):

note that if you are writing a non-ASP.NET application, some of the methods are duplicated in System.Net.WebUtility as of .NET 4.0 ([WebUtility Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility_methods.aspx)) so you do not need to take a dependency on the ASP.NET assembly to perform HTML encoding and decoding.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Net;

var decodedtext = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(text);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.